# GitHub Java Project help eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, git, github, egit

Whenever I pull from Git is is successful, but then when I try to turn it into a java project, it doesn't work. I can make the pull into a java project, but i cant make it to be a master branch so i can commit to the project.I need to know what the problem is so i can start working on my project, I am fairly new to git. I've tried to restart eclipse and even reinstall it!! help! **[I am using eclipse mars and have egit.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Bgpe.png)**

Comment: What is the error message displayed? Which repository are you pulling/cloning from (link the url)?  Do you have push access to that? If not you can only fork it and commit to your own fork.

Comment: You have not really given us any information to work with. Are you the owner of the git project with proper rights to commit to Master? Have you set up your remote origin? Can you explain the significance of your picture? When you import the project, are you importing it as a Java project, or a git project?